# How to use arrayformula in Google Sheets to calculate the number of days between non adjacent data readings

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Approximately once a week, I am taking data counts from a number of units.  The counts are recorded along with the date and unit # and and reset to zero.  In order to determine the count/day during the intervening period I need to determine the date of the previous reading for that particular unit:

| ​Date | Unit # | Data | Other Data | Date of previous reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/21/23 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 9/21/23 | 2 | 0 |  |  |
| 9/21/23 | 3 | 0 |  |  |
| 9/22/23 | 1 |  | Other data |  |
| 9/27/23 | 3 |  | Other data |  |
| 9/28/23 | 1 | 114 |  | 9/21/23 |
| 9/28/23 | 3 | 157 |  | 9/21/23 |
| 10/1/23 | ALL |  | Other data |  |
| 10/4/23 | 1 |  | Other data |  |
| 10/4/23 | 3 |  | Other data |  |
| 10/5/23 | 2 | 110 |  | 9/21/23 |
| 10/5/23 | 3 | 112 |  | 9/28/23 |
| 10/6/23 | ALL |  | Other data |  |
| 10/12/23 | 1 | 130 |  | 9/28/23 |
| 10/12/23 | 2 | 62 |  | 10/5/23 |
| 10/12/23 | 3 | 139 |  | 10/5/23 |

BTW. The dates are always increasing and the data are interspersed with readings that can be ignored (and are thus, presumably, irrelevant to the question but shown for context).

I am able to find the "previous dates" using INDEX, FILTER, and COUNTIFS:
INDEX(FILTER(B$2:B2,D$2:D2<>"", C$2:C2=C2),COUNTIFS(C$2:C2,"="&C2,D$2:D2,"<>"&"")-1,1)
but I need to copy this formula to each row and would prefer to use ARRAYFORMULA but neither INDEX nor COUNTIFS work with ARRAYFORMULA.

Comment: Please format your markdown table.

Comment: My apologies - the formatting appeared correct when I went to edit it (and it took a while to figure out how to correctly create a table)

Comment: `the formatting appeared correct`. Yep, that happens to me too. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, I managed to obtain the expected results with this formula :

```
=map(A2:A17,B2:B17,D2:D17,
 lambda(date,unit,otherData, 
  iferror(
   let(filtered_data,
    filter(
     indirect("$A$2:$A$"&row(date)),
     indirect("$C$2:$C$"&row(date))<>"",
     indirect("$B$2:$B$"&row(date))=unit,
     indirect("$A$2:$A$"&row(date))<>date
    ),
    if(otherData="",
     index(filtered_data,
     counta(filtered_data)),""
    )
   )
  ,"")
 )
)
```

Obviously, you can extend the inputs in the map formula to fit your need.

I would like to point out that this formula works with increasing dates only.

Let me know if something is not working properly or if you need more details :)

Antoine

Comment: Excellent - many thanks though I did change the formula to look at the actual data rather than "other data":
map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,lambda(date,unit,data, iferror(let(filtered_data,filter(indirect("$A$2:$A$"&row(date)),indirect("$C$2:$C$"&row(date))<>"",indirect("$B$2:$B$"&row(date))=unit,indirect("$A$2:$A$"&row(date))<>date),if(data<>"",index(filtered_data,counta(filtered_data)),"")),"")))